# pygeos.STRtree could not be pickled yet

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I'm trying to read the pickle file that has a geo dtatframe.
It was working fine on colab until I restarted the runtime

```
test = 'derived edges.pkl'  
testdf = pd.read_pickle(test)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-eb97f2da93db> in <module>()
      1 test = 'derived edges.pkl'
----> 2 testdf = pd.read_pickle(test)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression, storage_options)
    215                     # RawIOBase, BufferedIOBase, TextIOBase, TextIOWrapper, mmap]";
    216                     # expected "IO[bytes]"
--> 217                     return pickle.load(handles.handle)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    218             except excs_to_catch:
    219                 # e.g.

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/geopandas/array.py in __setstate__(self, state)
    422     def __setstate__(self, state):
    423         if compat.USE_PYGEOS:
--> 424             geoms = pygeos.from_wkb(state[0])
    425             self._crs = state[1]
    426             self._sindex = None  # pygeos.STRtree could not be pickled yet

KeyError: 0
```